# Как правильно называть собственные HTTP заголовки?

Tags: http, https

До этого момента называл как нравится - мог начать с `X-` (например: `X-Title`), а мог с аббревиатуры проекта (например: `SO-Title`).

Всегда в такие моменты было интересно узнать как правильно, но поиск в гугл не помогал - бросал и использовал в проектах заголовки по нраву.

Но вот сейчас, в очередной раз, решил поставить точку для себя в этом вопросе.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то рекомендации по оформлению кастомных заголовков? Или в целом я делал все правильно - можно писать как душе угодно?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions

Comment: @coolsv спасибо